# CSS nav bar too long

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have been fussing with this website header for a little while on a site. It's a WordPress site. The header navigation bar sticks out too far off of the main blog entries. I have tried changing many things but they all cause other problems.

I have tried reducing the width from 100% and putting a margin but that makes a problem when the site is resized or shown on a smaller screen.

I have tried centering it, but causes same kind of problems.

This is my problem below. The white navigation bar sticks out too far.

(I have removed some of the code that seems unnecessary to help with reading)

[image: My Problem]

Here is the css code that controls the menu background

```
#menu_background {
    width:100%; text-align:right; padding:10px 0; 
    margin-bottom:15px; /* for IE */ filter:alpha(opacity=95); /* CSS3 standard */
    opacity:0.95;z-index:300; box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.07); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
}
```

and here is the html from the main part, I removed the code just make it shorter. It's not inside any other divs.

```
<div id="menu_background">
</div><!--#menu_background-->
```

Comment: The header should be contained within a top level container that defines the maximum width for the content of your site.  That will keep everything aligned.  But in general your question needs to be more specific and more context provided to get anything useful.

Comment: Ah well i figured it out i had a margin down the way that was causing it. Stupid thing. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post (and accept) a self answer to this explaining your solution, could be helpful to others. Thanks.